# How to set Webpack to keep the same version hash if the file hasn't changed?

Tags: node.js, laravel, webpack, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

I am using [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix) which uses webpack in the background. In my `webpack.mix.js` I have set `.version()` on some files. Whenever I run `npm run production`, it calls:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --optimize-minimize --config=webpack.config.js
```

End result is a `mix-manifest.json` and files that look like this:

```
public/js/filename.5b68f51bca29a91b2d02.js
```

**How can I set webpack to keep the same Hash (i.e. `5b68f51bca29a91b2d02`) if the file hasn't changed?**

Is there a webpack config for that? (other than just removing `.version()` from the end webpack mix declarations)

Comment: My guess is that is due to `[hash]` which is a per build hash vs `[chunkhash]` see https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/153#issuecomment-225017219

Comment: The hash and therefore the filename is not going to change if you don't change the file content

Comment: BTW the latest version of laravel mix retains the filename but rather adds a hash as a query parameter when you use `mix('js/filename.js')`. But the same rule applies the hash stays the same if the content is the same